# Creating large amount of tasks/threads and waiting for them all to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm writing a fairly simple Raytracer and I've run into runtime limitations because the program is single-threaded. The result I've been finding through google all answer this type of question with two or three tasks to be handled.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();

        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff()));
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff()));
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff()));

        Task.WaitAll(taskList);

        Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }

    static void doStuff()
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

I'm looking at atleast 10,000 individual threads, if implemented naively. The solution above doesn't seem like the optimal one in this scenario. Is there a part of the standard library that supports this, or is there a Nuget package that has something like this implemented? It might also just be me baing stupid, and >10,000 threads in a List is not a problem at all. Then the issue becomes when the cutoff is. I would need 12500000 tasks/threads in some instances, which I'm pretty sure is way too many for a list.

Below is roughly how I would create a new thread/task as it stands now.

```
for (var x = 0; x < image.Width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < image.Height; y++) {
        var coordinates = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        var task = new Task(() => {
            RenderSinglePixel(coordinates);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, having more threads than processor cores for compute-bound tasks is bad.

Comment: That's what I thought too. What is the proper way to handle my situation?

Comment: I'll try to add an example.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Using the Task class, you shouldn't run into the problem as they are built on top of the thread pool. The CLR will start the tasks as a CPU thread becomes available.

Comment: Creating a `Task` does **not imply** creating a thread. Only tasks created with `LongRunning` flag actually create a dedicated thread for them. All other tasks are queued and then run on already created threads like UI thread or on tasks from the deault thread pool.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: a `Task` is NOT a thread.

Comment: @Phaeze @quetzalcoatl If you keep repeatedly calling `Task.Run()` with methods that don't finish for a very long time (hundreds of seconds, say), then the number of threads created WILL keep going up. If you don't believe me, run the second example in my question and change the sleep to `Thread.Sleep(100000)`. You'll see that the number of threads goes up to well over 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list (or other `IEnumerable<T>`) of values that you want to process using multiple threads, you can use `.AsParallel()` to do so.

This intelligently limits the number of threads that are spawned simultaneously, depending on the processor capabilities. However, note that you should only use this when the amount of work per item is relatively large.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var numbersToProcess = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);

            numbersToProcess.AsParallel().ForAll(doStuff);
        }

        static void doStuff(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is processing {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, value);
            Thread.Sleep(250); // Simulate compute-bound task.
        }
    }
}
```

An alternate approach is to create task for each method call, but it becomes more difficult to know when all the threads have completed unless you store the tasks in order to wait for them to complete (but the thread pool usage will ensure that the number of threads doesn't get too large):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var numbersToProcess = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);

            foreach (int number in numbersToProcess)
            {
                int n = number;
                Task.Run(() => doStuff(n));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void doStuff(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is processing {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, value);
            Thread.Sleep(250); // Simulate compute-bound task.
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** This approach does run the risk of a runaway number of threads being created, if each call to`doStuff()` takes a very long time. If you change the `Thread.Sleep(250)` to `Thread.Sleep(100000)` and run the program, you'll see that a large number of threads are created.

But your best bet is likely to use [the DataFlow TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I suppose I could create an array of the coordinates that should be processed, but that seems horribly inefficient. Is there not a ThreadPool-like method to doing this?

Comment: @Herbstein You CAN just use `Tasks` as per my second example, but as I point out, knowing when the last task is complete is more awkward. But it sounds like you will probably want to look into the DataFlow TPL - there's a big learning curve with that, but it's likely to be most suitable for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will probably implement a `Task`-only version now, and then look into the DataFlow TPL when I have a little more time. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm recommending the Parallel loop for small bodies pattern described below since the OP have a lot of pixels to render rather than doing a plain parallel loop as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Parallel loop for small bodies pattern.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.110).aspx

> When a Parallel.For loop has a small body, it might perform more slowly than the equivalent sequential loop, such as the for loop in C# and the For loop in Visual Basic. Slower performance is caused by the overhead involved in partitioning the data and the cost of invoking a delegate on each loop iteration. To address such scenarios, the Partitioner class provides the Partitioner.Create method, which enables you to provide a sequential loop for the delegate body, so that the delegate is invoked only once per partition, instead of once per iteration.

The Parallel Loop for Small Bodies pattern essentially partitions your enumerable and executes the loop in multiple threads depending on number of processors.  Each thread will have its own partition group to work on.

This pattern is better (more performant) than the normal Parallel Loop in this scenario because it avoids the overhead of creating more threads than necessary.

Using threads more than CPU cores will just slow down the overall speed of the processing

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon, if the link ever dies the answer no longer has any value. Please include the relevant information from the link in your answer in a quote block.

Comment: @Devlin The Parallel Loop for Small Bodies pattern essentially partitions your enumerable and executes the loop in multiple threads depending on number of processors, Each thread will have its own partition group to work on.

Comment: @MarkMenchavez - so why don't you explain that in your answer, rather than in the comments?  As it stands, your answer is poor quality.  It could be improved if you explained how it resolves the OP's problem, and, even better, show an example of how it works.

Comment: Answer edited.  Thanks for your comments and suggestions.